# SQL Server : Select ... From with FULL JOIN with a Default value for a column

Tags: sql-server, select, join, case, full-outer-join

I created a table, `tblNewParts` with 3 columns:

```
NewCustPart
AddedDate
Handled
```

and I am trying to `FULL JOIN` it to an existing table, `tblPartsWorkedOn`.
`tblNewParts` is defined to have Handled defaulted to `'N'`...

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.tblPartsWorkedOn AS BASE
FULL JOIN dbo.tblNewParts AS ADDON ON BASE.[CustPN] = ADDON.[NewCustPart]
WHERE ADDON.[Handled] IS NULL
ORDER BY [CustPN] DESC
```

And I want the field `[Handled]` to come back as `'N'` instead of `NULL` when I run the query. The problem is that when there aren't any records in the new table, I get `NULL`'s instead of `'N'`s.

I saw a `SELECT CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN defaultval ELSE col1 END` as a mostly suitable answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283120/assign-default-value-to-a-datacolumn-in-a-select-statement). I am wondering if this will work in this instance, and how would I write that in T-SQL for SQL Server 2012? I need all of the columns from both tables, rather than just the one.

I'm making this a question, rather than a comment on the cited link, so as to not obscure the original link's question.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: What is stopping you from trying this solution?

Comment: @IvanStarostin still being fairly new to SQL, and hitting walls because it's not a full programming language, I asked for help and then went off to try things also. I posted my "answer" as it now works for me, and I am hoping that it will stay up for others that think like I do, and not as the typical SQL Programmer. :D

Comment: Feel free to post some more answers with demonstration of `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` functions usage.

Answer (score 1):

Name the column (alias.column_name) in select statement and use ISNULL(alias.column,'N').

Thanks

Comment: Can you further explain this, with an example? I would love to know how to fit this into what I am doing, as I am going to be using a lot of T-SQL in the foreseeable future! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

After many iterations I found the answer, it's kind of bulky but here it is anyway. Synopsis:

Yes, the `CASE` statement does work, but it gives the output as an unnamed column. Also, in this instance to get all of the original columns AND the corrected column, I had to use `SELECT *, CASE...END as [ColumnName]`.

But, here is the better solution, as it will place the information into the correct column, rather than adding a column to the end of the table and calling that column `'Unnamed Column'`.

```
Select [ID], [Seq], [Shipped], [InternalPN], [CustPN], [Line], [Status], 
       CASE WHEN ADDON.[NewCustPart] IS NULL THEN BASE.[CustPN] ELSE 
            ADDON.[NewCustomerPart] END as [NewCustPart],
       GetDate() as [AddedDate], 
       CASE WHEN ADDON.[Handled] IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE ADDON.[Handled] END as [Handled]

        from dbo.tblPartsWorkedOn as BASE
        full join dbo.tblNewParts as AddOn ON Base.[CustPN] = AddOn.NewCustPart

        where AddOn.Handled = 'N' or AddOn.Handled is null
        order by [NewCustPart] desc
```

This sql code places the `[CustPN]` into `[NewCustPart]` if it's null, it puts a `'N'` into the field `[Handled]` if it's null and it assigns the date to the `[AddedDate]` field. It also only returns records that have not been handled, so that you get the ones that need to be looked at; and it orders the resulting output by the `[NewCustPart]` field value.

Resulting Output looks something like this: (I shortened the DateTime for the output here.)

```
[ID]   [SEQ]   [Shipped]   [InternalPN]   [CustPN]   [Status]   [NewCustPart]   [AddedDate]   [Handled]
1      12      N           10012A         10012A     UP         10012A          04/02/2016    N
...
```

Rather than with the nulls:

```
[ID]   [SEQ]   [Shipped]   [InternalPN]   [CustPN]   [Status]   [NewCustPart]   [AddedDate]   [Handled]
1      12      N           10012A         10012A     UP         NULL            NULL          NULL
...
```

I'm leaving this up, and just answering it rather than deleting it, because I am fairly sure that someone else will eventually ask this same question. I think that lots of examples showing how and why something is done, is a very helpful thing to have as not everything can be generalized. Just some thoughts and I hope that this helps someone else!